# How do I grant save permission to a user in Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to grant a user the 'save' permission to a workbook in Tableau Server 9.1. He has permissions at the data source, project, and workbooks levels. He is able to 'save as' but not 'save'. I am not sure if there is something else I should check. How do I grant 'save' permission to a user for a particular workbook in Tableau Server?

Comment: Is the user an Interactor or Publisher? If not, try giving him one of these roles.

Comment: The user is a Publisher.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything seems fine. Maybe a hint: if the user is a Publisher, but he is in a group and that group doesn't have publisher permission to the workbook/project, he'll still be unable to save.

Answer (score 1):

To save changes to a workbook, a user must have a **site role of Publisher and must have the Save capabilities allowed for the workbook.**

To grant Save and Download permissions

1.Set the site role of the user to Publisher. For more information, see Change a Site Role.

2.Create a permission rule for a group or user at the project or workbook level. Set the following capabilities:

To allow users (Publisher site role) to edit and save changes to existing and new workbooks

> ```
> Permission  For the project    For specified workbooks in the project 
> Web Edit    Allowed            Allowed 
> Download    Allowed            Allowed 
> Save        Allowed            Allowed
> ```

Note: In this scenario, because permissions are set the same way for both projects and workbooks, if you want to apply project-level permission changes to all workbooks within the project, click Assign Permissions to Contents in the project permission settings.

To allow users (Publisher site role) to edit and save changes to new workbooks, but not overwrite existing workbooks

> ```
> Permission  For the project    For specified workbooks in the project 
> Web Edit    Allowed            Allowed 
> Download    Allowed            Allowed 
> Save        Allowed            Denied
> ```

Please note that the permissions must be set manually on each workbook. Do not click Assign Permissions to Contents in the project permissions. If you do click Assign Permissions to Contents, the project permissions will overwrite the workbook permissions, thereby granting users access to save changes to existing workbooks.

3. Save the rule and now you can have save enabled for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other users who have save permissions for the workbook? If so, then comparing their group membership may provide more detail as to why this particular user cannot be granted save permissions.

As per @astro11's comment, it is likely that the user is a member of a group that has been explicitly denied save permissions (since deny trumps allow).